# How can I split every space apart from when the space is within quotes?

Tags: php, regex

I know How to split spaces into an array:

```
$array =  array_filter(preg_split('/\s+/',$a));
```

But if the string `$a` has quotes I want the regex to ignore all spaces within.

---

For example:

String:

> @  IN  TXT "V=SPF1 A MX IP4:x.x.x.x ~ALL"

Would split into array parts:

- @
- IN
- TXT
- "V=SPF1 A MX IP4:x.x.x.x ~ALL" *(Don't mind if contains ' " ' or not)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### preg_split

You can leverage `PCRE` verbs `SKIP` and `FAIL` that are used to discard patterns. The idea is to discard what are within quotes, so you can use a regex like this:

```
".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s+
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kW2jO2/1)**

[image]

However, if you want to use `"` or `'` you can use this regex:

```
(["']).*?\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s+

$keywords = preg_split("/([\"']).*?\1(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\s+/", $a);
```

### preg_match_all

On the other hand, you can also use another regex to capture what you want by using something like this:

```
(".*"|'.*?'|\S+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/kW2jO2/2)**

```
$re = "/(\".*\"|'.*?'|\\S+)/"; 
$str = "@ IN TXT \"V=SPF1 A MX IP4:x.x.x.x ~ALL\" 'asdf asdf'"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: For some reason this does not include `"V=SPF1 A MX IP4:x.x.x.x ~ALL"` in the array?

Comment: @Maximilian great, glad to help. Btw, updated the answer with another approach for preg_match_all

Answer (score 0):

You can try`\".*\"|\'.*\'|[^\s]*?(?=\s|$)`, that should match what you're looking for.

https://regex101.com/r/aZ7nJ8/2

A fairly crude way, but does the trick it and it contains the quotes, if you dont want them, you can always use lookaheads and lookbehinds.